# Improper integral of $\dfrac{x^2}{ e^x−1}$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I am trying to evaluate 
$$\int_0^t \frac{x^2}{ e^x−1}dx$$
for $t>0$.
I tried integrating by parts, like follows: 
$$\int_0^t x\cdot\frac{xe^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}}dx=t\cdot Li_2(1-e^{-t})-\int_0^t Li_2(1-e^{-x}) dx,$$ where $Li$ is the dilogarithm function. But then, how can I proceed? 
Any suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: Integrate by parts twice, then see what's left...

Comment: As an aside, $~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\dfrac{x^n}{e^x-1}dx=n!~\zeta(1+n),~$ and $~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\dfrac{x^n}{e^x+1}dx=n!~\eta(1+n).~$ See [Riemann $\zeta$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) and [Dirichlet $\eta$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function).

Answer (score 5):

Depending on whether a series might do, it looks easier to integrate $x^2(e^{-x}+e^{-2x}+e^{-3x}+\cdots)$ by parts instead.

Comment: I agree that this is the best approach to the problem. Each term $x^2 e^{-nx}$ integrates to $2/n^3$, which results in a sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2/n^3 = 2 \zeta(3)$. Each term integrates in a a straightforward way by using integration by parts.

Answer (score 3):

**-$1^{st}$ Approach:**

Using integration by parts you get

$$\begin{align}\int \frac{x^2}{e^x-1}dx &= x^2 \ (\ln (1-e^x) - x) - \int 2x\ln (1-e^x) - 2x^2 dx \\&= x^2\ln (1-e^x) - \frac{x^3}{3} +2xLi_{2}(e^x) - 2Li_{3}(e^x) +C \end{align}$$

Evaluating separetly $\int x\ln(1-e^x) dx$ we have

$$\int x\ln(1-e^x) dx = -xLi_{2}(e^x) + Li_{3}(e^x)$$

Where
$$\int \ln (1-e^x) = -Li_2(e^x) + C_1 (*) \ \ \text{and}\ \  \int Li_2(e^x) = Li_3(e^x) + C_2$$

$(*)$ Write $\ln(1 - e^x)$ in series and use integration term by term.

**- $2^{nd}$ Approach:**

$$\zeta (3) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(3)}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{3-1}}{e^x-1} dx \Rightarrow \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2}}{e^x-1} dx = 2\zeta(3) $$

See more about [Riemann Zeta Function](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph116A/rzeta_11.pdf).

Comment: Sorry, I want to ask a question. I want to evaluate this integral in a real interval like [0,t]. Then, in the first approach, when you calculate the integral of $ln(1-e^x)$, $x$ is a positive real number and then the logaritm is not real. Isn't it? How can I proceed in the real case?

Comment: @Betty Well, to find the integral of ln(1−ex) all you need is to expand $\ln(1−e^x)=−\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k(−e^{kx})}{k}$, where $\Re e(e^x)<1$. Then you integrate term by term to get $Li_2(e^x) + C$, so it's real.

Comment: @Betty It is $-Li_2(e^x) + C$. I mistyped.

Comment: so if for $x>0$, as $e^x>1$ this method cannot be appied...

Comment: @Betty In general there is an analytic continuation $Li_2(z) :=-\int_{0}^{z} \frac{ln(1-t)}{t}dt $ for $|z|> 1$.

Comment: @Betty If I may add, this question was really great.

Answer (score 3):

$\int_0^t\dfrac{x^2}{e^x-1}dx$

$=\int_0^t\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{B_nx^{n+1}}{n!}dx$ (with the formula in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Generating_function)

$=\left[\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{B_nx^{n+2}}{n!(n+2)}\right]_0^t$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{B_nt^{n+2}}{n!(n+2)}$

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$\eqalign{\dfrac{d}{dx} \text{Li}_n(e^x) &= \text{Li}_{n-1}(e^x),\ n \ge 3\cr
\dfrac{d}{dx} \text{Li}_2(e^x) &= -\ln(1-e^x)\cr
\dfrac{d}{dx} \left(-\ln(1 - e^x)\right) &= \dfrac{e^x}{1-e^x} = \dfrac{1}{1-e^x} - 1\cr}$$
So we can do integration by parts
$$ \eqalign{\int \dfrac{x^n \; dx}{1-e^x} &= \dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} + \int \dfrac{x^n e^x\; dx}{1 - e^x} \cr &= \dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} - x^n\ln(1 - e^x)
+ n \int x^{n-1} \ln(1 - e^x)\; dx\cr
&= \dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}  - x^n\ln(1 - e^x) - n x^{n-1} \text{Li}_2(e^x) + n(n-1) \int x^{n-2} \text{Li}_2(e^x)\; dx}$$
etc.